# (Excel VBA) Finding Values Based on Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have a table which contains two column. They represent date and a corresponding value respectively. What i want to do is get mean values of each month and create another table with monthly mean values and years. I write a simple code with "for" which works perfectly but it takes a while since there are around 40000 rows. I am curious if there are other ways to do it in significantly shorter time. Thank you.

```
TABLE
...
09.07.1908  63.5
10.07.1908  59.7
11.07.1908  49
12.07.1908  44.7
.......
.......
12.05.2003  32.45
13.05.2003  38.33
.......



 OUTPUT
        JANUARY FEBRUARY MARCH ...  
 1908    12.53    23.45  45.87 ...
 1909    45.23    14.43  23.54 ...
 .................................
 .................................
 2014    23.65    56.87  12.43 ...




Dim i, j, index1, index2 As Integer
Dim mean, sum As Double

index1 = 0 
index2 = 1
For i = 1908 To 2014
  For j = 1 To 12
    For k = 3 To 39000
      If Month(Sheet1.Cells(k, 1).Value) = j And Year(Sheet1.Cells(k,1).Value) = i Then
      sum = sum + Sheet1.Cells(k, 2).Value
      index1 = index1 + 1
      End If
    Next
  mean = sum / index1
  Sheet5.Cells(index2 + 2, j + 1).Value = sum / index1
  sum = 0
  index1 = 0
  Next
index2 = index2 + 1
Next
```

Comment: if your code works and you just want to look for its best optimization then post it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Read data is a little faster using arrays but writing all the data at once can easily speed up your code 100 fold on a large dataset.  Processing 39000 rows x 2 Columns and writing 1 Rows x 13 Columns (Header Row) and writing 106 Rows x 13 Columns took: 0.125 Seconds.

```
Sub Refactor()
    Dim Start: Start = Timer
    Dim arData, arSums(1908 To 2014, 0 To 12), arCounts(1908 To 2014, 1 To 12)
    Dim m As Long, x As Long, y As Long

    With Sheet1
        arData = .Range("A3", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    For x = 1 To UBound(arData, 1)
        m = Month(arData(x, 1))
        y = Year(arData(x, 1))

        arSums(y, m) = arSums(y, m) + arData(x, 2)
        arCounts(y, m) = arCounts(y, m) + 1
    Next

    For x = LBound(arSums, 1) To UBound(arSums, 1)
        arSums(x, 0) = x

        For y = 1 To 12
            If Not IsEmpty(arCounts(x, y)) Then arSums(x, y) = arSums(x, y) / arCounts(x, y)
        Next
    Next

    Sheet5.Range("A1").Resize(1, 13) = Array("Year", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
    Sheet5.Range("A2").Resize(106, 13).Value = arSums
    Debug.Print Timer - Start
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great information. This is really a "significant" difference :) .